# 'cd ios' && 'pod install' or 'npx pod-install'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native, pod-install

I have seen both alternatives out there but I'm not sure about the difference between them

I've tried both but in different projects because I don't want to screw any of them, and actually haven't seen any difference.
Any explanation would be really appreciated!

Comment: [Looks like](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pod-install) `npx pod-install` is just doing a few additional checks for you before launching Cocoapods.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.